# Finding Expectation and Variance of $X_1$ and $X_2$

Tags: random-variables, expectation, variance

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be random variables such that $E(X_i)=μ_i$ and $Var(X_i)=α_i^2$.
A. Find $E(X_1+X_2)$ and $E(X_1-X_2)$ in terms of the μ's and α's.
B. Suppose that $E(X_1X_2)=α$. Find $Var(X_1+X_2)$. When does it equal $Var(X_1)+Var(X_2)$?
C. Assume that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. Find $Var(3X_1-2X_2)$.

Please explain how to solve these questions because I don't know where to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A) Let $Y$ be a linear combination of (say) two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$. Specifically, let $Y=cX1+dX_2$ where $c$ and $d$ are constants. Then
$$E(Y)=E(cX_1+dX_2)=cE(X_1)+dE(X_2).$$
In particular, $E(X_1+X_2)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)$ and $E(X_1-X_2)=E(X_1)-E(X_2)$. So the answers are $\mu_1+\mu_2$ and $\mu_1-\mu_2$. In the rest of the answer, we indicate the pieces that go into the calculation, but do not put the pieces together.

B) The variance of any random variable $W$ is $E(W^2)-(E(W))^2$. A very important fact!

Let $W=X_1+X_2$. Then 
$$E(W^2)=E(X_1^2+2X_1X_2+X_2^2)=E(X_1^2)+E(X_2^2)+E(2X_1X_2).$$
Now use the fact that $E(X_i^2)=\text{Var}(X_i)+(E(X_i))^2$, and that we know $E(X_1X_2)$ to finish the calculation.

C) It is a general fact that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, then the variance of $cX_1+dX_2$ is equal to $c^2\text{Var}(X_1)+d^2\text{Var}(X_2)$. For a proof, we can use the fact that the variance of $cX_1+dX_2$ is
$$E((cX_1+dX_2)^2)-(E(cX_1+dX_2))^2,$$ 
and then calculate as in Part B. We will be using the fact that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, then $E(X_1X_2)=E(X_1)E(X_2)$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation because i didnt know where the equation were being derived from.

Comment: You are welcome. I have left some things for you to do. If there are any difficulties or questions, please ask. An answer may not come until tomorrow, it is getting late here.

Comment: Just one thing im not sure of is if variance of any random variable W is E(W^2)−(E(W))2. You are only solving for E(W^2) but what about -)−(E(W))2? Thanks for your time

Comment: The usual *definition* of variance is $E((W-E(W)^2)$. This is actually kind of useful here, but *most of the time*, it is easier to use the fact that the variance is $E(W^2)-(E(W))^2$, the mean of the square minus the square of the mean. When you are using this to find the variance, you do need to know the mean, but in most cases we do or can find it easily.

Comment: Hey aside from this question, is this expression true:  μ=sigma and Var(X)=$sigma^2$

Comment: My comment yesterday was inaccurate. The symbol $\mu$ is often used for mean. and $\sigma$ for standard deviation. Having $\mu=\sigma$ is infrequent. In the problem above they are using $\alpha_i$ for the variances of the $X_i$, but $\text{Var}$ as a generic term for variance.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple problem.

A). $\mathsf{E}(X_1+X_2)=\mathsf{E}(X_1)+\mathsf{E}(X_2)=\mu_1+\mu_2$ (since expectation is linear operator, it can be shown easily by taking convolution of distribution of $X_1+X_2$. Similarly $\mathsf{E}(X_1-X_2)=\mathsf{E}(X_1)-\mathsf{E}(X_2)=\mu_1-\mu_2$

B) $var(X_1)=\mathsf{E}((X_1+X_2)-(\mu_1+\mu_2))^2=\mathsf{E}((X_1-\mu_1)+(X_2-\mu_2))^2=\mathsf{E}((X_1-\mu_1)^2+(X_2-\mu_2)^2+2(X_1-\mu_1)(X_2-\mu_2))=\alpha_1+\alpha_2+2\mathsf{E}(X_1X_2-X_1\mu_2+X_2\mu_1+\mu_1\mu_2)=\alpha_1+\alpha_2+2(\alpha-\mu_1\mu_2) $

C) Since $X_1, X_2$ are independent, hence $Var(3X_1-2X_2)=9\alpha_1+4\alpha_2$.      $\square$

Comment: how did you get $\alpha_1+\alpha_2$

Comment: @Moose sum of variances